# No performance gain using async for web api methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to determine if I should use Async for my web Api project. As a test I created a method that calls a long running remote service and used Async/Await. I then wrote a synchronous method which does the same.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ProcessAsync()
{
    string uri = "http://mysrvc.azurewebsites.net"; //A service that sleeps for 10 seconds and returns "success". Does not use Async or await
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Json(content, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult Process()
{
    string uri = "http://mysrvc.azurewebsites.net";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var content = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return Json(content, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

After deploying the web api with above methods in IIS on a remote machine (Win 7), I called each method separately on multiple threads. They return response as expected, but I see no difference in the performance of the two methods. For 1-10 threads, both respond in 10 seconds. For 11-20 threads both take 20 seconds consistently.
Is the Async code above wrong? Does Async/Await improve performance of web applications?

Comment: What performance gain do you expect? Async method can't force another web service ("http://mysrvc.azurewebsites.net") to run faster. Async methods allow to spend web server resources more effectively - thus, async web site *could* serve more clients, because it doesn't block threads during I/O, but it won't run "faster", that sync one.

Comment: To continue on what Dennis said, Async methods are usually marginally slower than their sync counterparts due to the overhead of the callbacks, but they do scale better under load and that is why we use them.

Comment: Guess my question was a bit misleading, I am not expecting performance gain on a single call, but when I am making 20 simultaneous calls I was expecting the async method to take less time overall than the synchronous one. Otherwise what is the benefit of using Async?

Comment: The benifit is if your system can only handle 20 concurrent calls before getting significant performance drops the async version could maybe handle 30 concurrent calls before getting signifcant performance drops. The time per call will still be the same be it 1 call or 20. (Also 20 is really really low, when talking limits of iis usually you are in the 100's to 1000's of concurrent calls range)

Comment: @GKMaganty: 20 calls is nothing, especially, from single client process.

Comment: In my case, IIS on win7 is handling 10 simultaneous calls. Beyond that, the response time is just doubling. Is Win7 machine not a good candidate for this test?

Comment: You may need to change your test client.  You might need to override it's default behavior to allow more than 10 calls to occur to the same target host at once.  And as the above commenters have said, retry the test with 500-1000 calls being made at once and see the difference.

Comment: I see, I did not realize that it is my test client that is creating this limitation. I will test out with 500-1000 calls. Glad to know there is nothing wrong with actual code. Thank you!